# Numpy datetime format

Tags: python, numpy

First time post - I'm following a Data Analysis with Python Introduction course in Lynda.com. The instructor in the video is using Jupiter Notebooks, I am using Visual Studio Code to follow along but I've hit a snag with the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
import seaborn
import urllib

def findstation(s):
    found = {code: name for code, name in stations.items() if s in name}
    print(found)

def parsefile(filename):
    return np.genfromtxt(filename,
                            delimiter = dly_delimiter,
                            usecols = dly_usecols,
                            dtype = dly_dtype,
                            names = dly_names)

dly_delimiter = [11,4,2,4] + [5,1,1,1] * 31
dly_usecols = [1,2,3] + [4*i for i in range(1, 32)]
dly_dtype = [np.int32, np.int32, (np.str_, 4)] + [np.int32]*31
dly_names = ['year', 'month', 'obs'] + [str(day) for day in range(1,31+1)]

def unroll(record):
    startdate = np.datetime64('{}-{:02}'.format(record['year'],record['month']))
    dates = np.arange(startdate, startdate + np.timedelta64(1, 'M'), np.timedelta64(1, 'D'))
    rows = [(date, record[str(i+1)]) for i,date in enumerate(dates)]
    return rows

#urllib.request.urlretrieve('ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd-stations.txt', 'stations.txt')
lines = open('stations.txt','r').readlines()[:10]
#print(lines)

stations = {}

for line in open('stations.txt','r'):
    if "GSN" in line:
        fields = line.split()
        stations[fields[0]] = ' '.join(fields[4:])

print(len(stations))
#findstation('LIHUE')
#findstation('SAN DIEGO')
#findstation('MINNEAPOLIS')
#findstation('IRKUTSK')

datastations = ['USW00022536', 'USW00023188', 'USW00014922', 'RSM00030710']

daily = open('USW00022536.dly', 'r').readlines()[:10]
#print(daily)
lihue = parsefile('USW00022536.dly')
u_lihue = unroll(lihue)
print(u_lihue)
```

The following error message displays:

```
line 23, in unroll startdate = np.datetime64('{}-{:02}'.format(record['year'],record['month']))
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__
```

The code works using Jupiter Notebooks - thoughts?

Comment: Read [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html?highlight=datetime64) ??

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception you should always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [mcve], [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: What are the values of `record['year']` and `record['month']`? I would like to see if I can reproduce the error inside the Python shell.

Comment: @wwii - Thank you for input. I'll be sure to look at these and follow the instructions for next time.

Comment: @martineau - The year is in YYYY number format while the month is M number format. The dates are coming from the USW00022536.dly file provided in the exercise files. The file goes through the parsefile function which takes the data from the file and puts it into a NumPy array.

Answer (score 0):

With this `record` dictionary, the expression works:

```
In [225]: record = {'year': '2119', 'month': 12}
In [226]: '{}-{:02}'.format(record['year'],record['month'])
Out[226]: '2119-12'
In [227]: np.datetime64('{}-{:02}'.format(record['year'],record['month']))
Out[227]: numpy.datetime64('2119-12')
```

The purpose of the `format` expression is to create a string that `np.datetime64` can parse.  It's fairly picky about formats.

It would help to see the `record` object in the problem case.